# Is there any concept of angel numbers in Christianity?

Tags: angels, numerology

Just wanted to confirm if there is any concept believed in Christianity related to angel numbers or numerology? I have read in this angel number blog that it relates to Christianity. Just want to confirm. What I read is:

> **Meaning in the Bible**
>
> Seeing angel number 2323 signifies new and fresh life as well as harmony according to the Bible. The Holy Bible also suggests that these numbers 2 and 3 occurring twice have great divine power. The holy angels are reminding you that they are always watching over you and guiding you through every single thing.
>
> *Source*: [Angel number 2323](https://angelsnumbers.net/2323-angel-number/)

So I need the proper guidance please. Thanks.

Comment: The link is to an article that is merely opinion without any substantial reference to Christianity or to holy scripture.

Answer (score 5):

**Is there any concept of angel numbers in Christianity?**

The short answer is **no**.

> Angel numbers have grown in popularity in recent years due to the resurgence of New Age practices. While angel numbers might sound as if they have something to do with the angels of the Bible, they do not. There is nothing biblical about angel numbers, as nowhere in the Bible are we told about the existence of angel numbers. - [What Are Angel Numbers and Are They Biblical?](https://www.christianity.com/wiki/angels-and-demons/what-are-angel-numbers-and-are-they-biblical.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is one view of what Christians think about “angel numbers” and numerology:

> New Age observers have decided that numbers that show up repeatedly are not coincidental; rather, they are messages from angels or spirit guides.  There are several problems with a belief in angel numbers:

> • “Spirit guides” are not protective, helpful angels. When they actually exist, they are disguised demons attempting to lead us into sin or destruction. Interacting with demonic guides is expressly forbidden in the Bible (Leviticus 20:27). James 4:7 tells us to resist such beings, not trust and follow them.

> • Numerology is an occult practice that has no basis in Scripture and no place in the Christian life. Although the Bible uses numbers such as 7 and 40 to represent specific things, this does not mean that every number has a hidden meaning. Numerology is a form of fortune–telling, which the Bible absolutely condemns (Leviticus 19:31; Deuteronomy 18:10–13; Galatians 5:19–20).

> • God communicates with us through His Word, not the face of our alarm clock. He established the Bible to give us what we need to know about Him (2 Timothy 3:16–17) and wise counselors to help us apply the Bible to our lives (1 Corinthians 11:1). Nowhere in the Bible does it suggest God communicates through hidden meanings in numbers outside of the Bible.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/angel-numbers.html

As for the literal number of heavenly angels, the apostle John was granted a vision in which “he heard the voice of many angels, numbering thousands upon thousands, and ten thousand times ten thousand. They encircled the throne and the living creatures and the elders” (Revelation 5:11).

Moses said the Lord came to speak to him from Sinai with “myriads of holy ones,” or angels (Deuteronomy 33:2). The primary definition of myriad as an adjective is “innumerable,” or “countless”.

Daniel had a dream in which the Ancient of Days was attended by ten thousand times ten thousand of angels.  That’s 100 million!